# AssertionError on unit testing service layer (in Java using Spring)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Trying to unit test my service layer, this is my test code :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceCreateUserTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserCreateService userCreateService;

    @Test
    public void when_save_user_it_should_return_user() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test Name");

        when(userRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn(new User());

        User created = userCreateService.create(user);

        assertThat(created.getName()).isSameAs(user.getName());
    }
}
```

And this is my service code :

```
@Service
public class UserCreateService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User create(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when running :

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
```

Expecting:
<"Test Name">
and actual:

```
 <null>
```

to refer to the same object

Could someone shed some light here? Not sure what is missing in my test code. Perhaps something to do with my method imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a new User() in the userRepository.save() call. Therefore, when userRepository.save() is called it returns a new user object. Instead, return your given user.

```
when(userRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
```